# Php - Database safe in file

Tags: php, mysql

I have on my config file that line

```
$connection = mysqli_connect('$server', '$user', '$pass', '$host');
```

and in this config I don't close `$connection`. I only include this file and get `$connection` to `mysqli_query` and then close `$connection` but in function not in config file.
It is and dangerous if i do things like that ?
Its look this
[config.php](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KCsvG.png)

Comment: Define "dangerous".

Comment: Easier to attack database, hack or do damage to it.

Comment: No it is not dangerous, non-persistent connections and result sets are automatically destroyed at the end of script execution. See: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php